# Why does Vim position the caret one character off with $ (end of line)?

Tags: vim

Observe a line in a Vim instance:
[image]

Now I hit $:
[image]

Why does my cursor not go all the way to the end? Once I try inserting, the text gets inserted *before* the last character! Even if I try to move right again while still in normal mode I get the bell. Oddly, when in edit mode I can move to the actual end of line with the right arrow key!

[image]

Does anyone know why Vim does this? On 7.3 by the way. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use `a` instead of `i` to move the cursor to the next character and end up in insert mode.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>$</kbd> while in command mode causes the cursor to move to the end of the line, effectively highlighting the last character.  Hit <kbd>i</kbd> here to insert before the last character, or <kbd>a</kbd> to append to the line.  It is slightly ambiguous here, because you're using a pipe character as a cursor rather than a rectangular block cursor.  Have a look at ":help termcap-cursor-shape" if you want to change that.

If the goal is to append to the end of the line, <kbd>A</kbd> will jump to the end of the line and enter insert mode with a single keypress.

Answer (score 11):

Use <kbd>a</kbd> to append a character after the current.

Or, to go to the end of the line and append in 1 step, use capital `A`. I.e. <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

Similarly <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> to insert at the beginning of the line without first having to press <kbd>^</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

The cursor can't be between two characters, it is always on a character.

If you press `$` then `x`, you will correctly delete the last printable character of the current line.

What you are observing is the fact that using `i`, you are always inserting your text *before* the selected character. If you want to insert *after* the selected character, you have to use `a` or better `A` as it has already been mentioned.

In other words:
`i` means "insert before character under cursor".
`a` means "insert after character under cursor".

mnemonic for `a` : a for "append".